# How to start a foreach loop at a specific index in PHP

Tags: php

I am writing a `foreach` that does not start at the 0th index but instead starts at the first index of my array. Is there any way to offset the loop's starting point?

Comment: Wouldnt it be better if you use FOR instead ?

Comment: Handling the key-value pairs is a lot easier in a foreach loop and I guess that's the resaon he wanted to take a foreach. Or he even has a foreach and doesn't want to change a lot of code.

Answer (score 113):

Keep it simple.

```
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
   if ($k < 1) continue;
   // your code here.
}
```

See the [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) control structure in the manual.

Comment: I like that solution. Is continue available with every version of PHP?

Comment: http://ie2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php doesn't mention when it became available, so I assume it's been there from the beginning.

Comment: and, if the array is not indexed?

Comment: By the sound of it, Nialls Chavez's array is indexed from `0` to some high number, and he wants to do something from index `1` onward. In that situation, something like what I've written above will do nicely. Or, even shorter, `if (!$k) continue;`, perhaps.

Comment: Or, all PHP arrays are indexed. If they're not explicitly indexed, they're indexed from `0` on.

Comment: how about `if ($k == $firstIndex) continue;` where `$firstIndex = 0;` in case of numerical indexes or `$firstIndex = 'myFirstKeyIndex';` in cases of associative array ?

Comment: This is a great answer. How could one have the same simplicity with an associative array? For example, I have an array of states with the key as the abbreviation. I still want to start on the 25th element sometimes. How would I do that?

Comment: This works but be aware of time cost since you are looping trough whole array before getting to index required. If possible use for() loop instead.

Comment: The question is not limited to arrays. What about 'Traversable'?

Comment: See the "skipping records with foreach" section of the answer I linked in the comment above, @PHPst.

Answer (score 37):

A [`Foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) will reset the array:

> Note: When foreach first starts executing, the internal array pointer is automatically reset to the first element of the array. This means that you do not need to call reset()  before a foreach  loop.

Either use a `for` loop (only if this is *not* an associative array)

```
$letters = range('a','z');
for($offset=1; $offset < count($letters); $offset++) {
    echo $letters[$offset];
}
```

or a `while` loop (can be any array)

```
$letters = range('a','z');
next($letters);
while($letter = each($letters)) {
    echo $letter['value'];
}
```

or with a [`LimitIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php)

```
$letters = new LimitIterator(new ArrayIterator(range('a','z')), 1);
foreach($letters as $letter) {
    echo $letter;
}
```

which lets you specify start offset and count through the constructor.

All of the above will output the letters b to z instead of a to z

Comment: LimitIterator this is it. ;)

Comment: Regarding `each` Warning This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 8.0.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php

Answer (score 23):

You can use the [`array_slice`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function:

```
$arr = array(); // your array
foreach(array_slice($arr, 1) as $foo){
   // do what ever you want here
}
```

Of course, you can use whatever offset value you want. In this case, `1` 'skip' the first element of the array.

Comment: Worth nothing that this will require making a copy of that chunk of the array. Could be a bad thing if the array is large.

Comment: You are right... this will work better for short arrays. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

In a foreach you cant do that. There are only two ways to get what you want:

1. Use a for loop and start at position 1
2. use a foreach and use a something like if($key>0) around your actual code

A foreach does what its name is telling you. Doing something for every element :)

**EDIT**: OK, a very evil solution came just to my mind. Try the following:

```
foreach(array_reverse(array_pop(array_reverse($array))) as $key => $value){
    ...
}
```

That would reverse the array, pop out the last element and reverse it again. Than you'll have a element excluding the first one.

But I would recommend to use one of the other solutions. The best would be the first one.

And a variation: You can use array_slice() for that:

```
foreach(array_slice($array, 1, null, true) as $key => $value){
    ...
}
```

But you should use all three parameters to keep the keys of the array for your foreach loop:

Comment: using array_slice it is possible to do this in a foreach loop, but that practice should be highly discouraged and punishable by having to read that sort of code.

Comment: That's why I pointed out that it's an EVIL method to do that. But I wouldn't use any of the solutoins personally. I would use a if statement or a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a for loop would be the better way to go here, but if you think you MUST use foreach you could shift the first element off the array and unshift it back on:

```
$a = array('foo','bar');
$temp = array_shift($a);
foreach ( $a as $k => $v ) {
  //do something
}
array_unshift($a, $temp);
```

Comment: Just noting that the `$k => $v` syntax is only for associative arrays. For indexed arrays, you just want `$a as $v`.

Comment: @Michael: the $k => $v will also work for indexed array and return the index number of the current value.

Answer (score 0):

Well no body said it but if you don't mind altering the array and if we want to start from the second element of the given array:

```
unset($array[key($array)]);
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    //do whatever
}
```

if you do mind, just add,

```
$saved = $array;
unset($array[key($array)]);
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    //do whatever
}
$array = $saved;
```

Moreover if you want to skip a given known index, just subtitute

```
key($array)
```

by the given index

Answer (score 0):

bismillah...
its simple just make own keys

```
 $keys=1;
    foreach ($namafile_doc as $value ) {
        $data['doc'.$keys]=$value;
        $keys++;
    }
```

may this answer can make usefull