# foreach outputs two arrays skip first

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to skip elements in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387193/how-to-skip-elements-in-foreach-loop)

I have the following foreach:

```
foreach($documents as $document): 
    print_r($document);
endforeach;
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Array
(
    [num] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Batman
            [url] => http://batman.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Superman
            [url] => http://superman.com
        )

)
```

The first array conatining [num] => 2, I dont want to use in my foreach when printing the result.

But how do I get rid of that array so it doesn't get printed when I use write print_r($document)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping with the `foreach` you can use [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php):

```
$first = true;

foreach($documents as $document) {
    if($first) {
        $first = false;
        continue;
    }

    print_r($document);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all answers. This fitted my purpose best.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [standard `for` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) with an incrementing index specifier and skip the first element.

```
for($i = 1; $i < count($documents); $i++) {
  print_r($documents[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to remove the first array completely, however my guess is that you can't do that. No worries - this should have you covered:

```
for( $i = 1; $i < count($documents); $i++ ):
   print_r($documents[$i]);
endfor;
```

Edit: I've created [a test case for you on Codepad.org](http://codepad.org/npfA57Sm).