# Objects in Objects, Skip one in foreach

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop over each object and show the team name on a website... however I want to skip the $variable->active key.

The number of teams varies...How can I skip the 'active' key?

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$active = $team->active;
if (isset($team->active)) {
foreach ($team as $data) {

    if (isset($data->idteam) != $active) {
        print_r($data);
        $return .= '<li><a href="a_set_active_team.php?set=' . $data->idteam . '"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> ' . $data->nameteam . '</a></li>';
    } else {
        $return .= "No Teams!";
    }
}
}
```

Here is my object:

```
teamAccess Object
(
[2] => Team Object
    (
        [nameteam] => Team 1
        [idteam] => 2
        [enabled] => 1
        [last_access_stamp] => 1399603014
        [create_stamp] => 4
        [update_stamp] => 1399167351
    )

[1] => Team Object
    (
        [nameteam] => Test Team
        [idteam] => 1
        [enabled] => 0
        [last_access_stamp] => 1399603014
        [create_stamp] => 0
        [update_stamp] => 0
    )

[3] => Team Object
    (
        [nameteam] => Team 3
        [idteam] => 3
        [enabled] => 1
        [last_access_stamp] => 1399603014
        [create_stamp] => 0
        [update_stamp] => 0
    )

[active] => 3
[alerts] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to skip elements in foreach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387193/how-to-skip-elements-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  This question is about detecting what you want to skip over, not how to skip in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `foreach`, you can capture the key, and check it in a condition to skip it:

```
foreach ($team as $key => $data) {
    if ($key != 'active') {
        $return .= '<li><a href="a_set_active_team.php?set=' . $data->idteam . '"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> ' . $data->nameteam . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Observation: it seems that the `teamAccess` object should have a `teams` property, which could be an array of team objects. This might be a better structure than having all of the data mixed together as root properties.