# Iterate a PHP array from a specific key

Tags: php, arrays, iterator

I know how to iterate an array in PHP, but I want to iterate an array from a specific key.

Assume that I have a huge array

```
$my_array = array(
    ...
    ...
    ["adad"] => "value X",
    ["yy"] => "value Y",
    ["hkghgk"] => "value Z",
    ["pp"] => "value ZZ",
    ...
    ...
)
```

I know the **key** where to start to iterate ("yy"). Now I want to iterate only from this key to another key.

I know that I don't want to do this:

```
$start_key = "yy";
foreach ($my_array as $key => $v)
{
    if ($key == $start_key)
        ...
}
```

I was looking for Iterator, but I don't think this is what I need.

Comment: you can use next() function.

Comment: Related: [How to start a foreach loop at a specific index in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3229905/2943403)

Answer (score 4):

Try combining array_search, array_key, and [LimitIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php). Using the example from the LimitIterator page and some extra bits:

```
$fruitsArray = array(
    'a' => 'apple',
    'b' => 'banana',
    'c' => 'cherry',
    'd' => 'damson',
    'e' => 'elderberry'
);

$startkey = array_search('d', array_keys($fruitsArray));

$fruits = new ArrayIterator($fruitsArray);

foreach (new LimitIterator($fruits, $startkey) as $fruit) {
    var_dump($fruit);
}
```

Starting at position 'd', this outputs:

```
string(6) "damson" string(10) "elderberry"
```

There is a limit to this approach in that it won’t loop around the array until the start position again. It will only iterate to the end of an array and then stop. You would have to run another `foreach` to do the first part of the array, but that can be easily done with the code we already have.

```
foreach (new LimitIterator($fruits, 0, $startkey-1) as $fruit) {
    var_dump($fruit);
}
```

This starts from the first element, up to the element before the one we searched for.

Comment: At that point you're better with `array_slice` instead of the iterator. But +1 as the OP explicitly asked for Iterators.

Comment: @bwoebi: `array_slice` makes a needless extra copy of everything.

Comment: @Jon I thought the Iterator variant would do a copy too, but source tells me that it's just copy on write, so, my fault, you're right.

Comment: But if you really care about performance, don't use `array_keys()` either, it creates a whole new array. (see my answer for the alternatives).

Comment: `array_keys` is only used in this approach as the key is non-numerical. If it is numerical, you can simply use `array_search`

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` always resets the array's array pointer. You just can't do that the way you imagine.

You still have a few ways. The *foreach* way is just skipping everything until you found the key once:

```
$start_key = "yy";
$started = false;
foreach ($my_array as $key => $v)
{
    if ($key == $start_key) {
        $started = true;
    }
    if (!$started) {
        continue;
    }
    // your code
}
```

You could as well work with the array pointer and use the `while (list($key, $v) = each($array))` method:

```
$start_key = "yy";
reset($array); // reset it to be sure to start at the beginning
while (list($key, $v) = each($array) && $key != $start_key); // set array pointer to $start_key
do {
    // your code
} while (list($key, $v) = each($array));
```

Alternatively, you can just extract the array you want to iterate over like [MarkBaker proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675816/iterate-a-php-array-from-a-specific-key/23675979#23675979).

Comment: The downvoter would had only upvoted it if it would have been encalsulated :) - https://eval.in/151642 (just an assumption, I can not speak for her)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
foreach(array_slice(
    $my_array,
    array_search(
        $start_key,array_keys($my_array)
    ),
    null,
    true) as $key => $v) {}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/QGce2p)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys) and  [array_search](http://php.net/array_search).

Like this:

```
$keys = array_keys( $my_array ); // store all of your array indexes in a new array
$position = array_search( "yy" ,$keys ); // search your starting index in the newly created array of indexes
if( $position == false ) exit( "Index doesn't exist" ); // if the starting index doesn't exist the array_search returns false

for( $i = $position; $i < count( $keys ); $i++  ) { // starting from your desired index, this will iterate over the rest of your array
    // do your stuff to $my_array[ $keys[ $i ] ] like:
    echo $my_array[ $keys[ $i ] ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$startkey = array_search('yy', array_keys($my_array));
$endkey = array_search('zz', array_keys($my_array));

$my_array2 = array_values($my_array);

for($i = $startkey; $i<=$endkey; $i++)
{
    // Access array like this
    echo $my_array2[$i];
}
```

Comment: @Jon `array_values()` uses numeric keys. And order is preserved compared to the original array.

Comment: @bwoebi: Yes, I just saw the `array_values`. Leaving the DV because this still loses the key information, so is not equivalent to the `foreach` shown in the question.

Comment: @Jon you can still get the key value of current element unless it has duplicates in array.

Comment: **Note:** To get current key value use `$key = array_search($my_array2[$i], $my_array); `

Comment: @krishna: And even then, you have to do a linear search over the array to find the key. Not good.

Answer (score 0):

If [this pull request](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/645) makes it through, you will be able to do this quite easily:

```
if (seek($array, 'yy', SEEK_KEY)) {
    while ($data = each($array)) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create the array once and then use it many times, you can index the array keys and that would be more efficient and clean than iterating all the elements every time. See this class as an example:

```
<?php


class IndexedArrayIterator implements Iterator {
    
    protected $data=array();
    protected $keyIndex=array();
    protected $reverseIndex=array();
    protected $position=0;
    protected $startIndex=0;
    protected $endIndex=0;
    
    function __construct($source) {
        $this->data=$source;
        $this->reindex();
    }
    
    function reindex() {
        // Reindexing is expensive, don't do it often
        // If you need to reindex every time you search, you loose the advantage
        // If you add elements, you must reindex
        $this->keyIndex = array_keys($this->data);
        $this->reverseIndex = array_flip($this->keyIndex);
    }
    
    function setStartKey($start) {
        $this->startIndex=$this->reverseIndex[$start];
    }
    
    function setEndKey($end) {
        $this->endIndex=$this->reverseIndex[$end];
    }
    

    /////
    ///      Iterator Interface
    //

    #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
    public function rewind() {
        $this->position=$this->startIndex;
    }

    #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
    public function current() {
        if($this->valid()) return $this->data[$this->key()];
        else return NULL;
    }

    #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
    public function key() {
        if($this->valid()) return $this->keyIndex[$this->position];
        else return NULL;
    }

    #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
    public function next() {
        ++$this->position;
    }

    #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
    public function valid() {
        if($this->position > $this->endIndex) return FALSE;
        return isset($this->keyIndex[$this->position]);
    }
    
}
```

Usage example:

```
$iterator=new IndexedArrayIterator([
    'one'=>'Item One',
    'two'=>'Item Two',
    'twoandhalf'=>'Item Two And Half',
    'three'=>'Item Three',
    'four'=>'Item Four',
]);

$iterator->setStartKey('two');
$iterator->setEndKey('three');

foreach($iterator as $key=>$value) {
    echo($key.': '.$value."\r\n");
}
```

Working code:

https://3v4l.org/EP0fL

Comment: Your `echo` does not benefit from the use of parentheses.  There is no benefit to prepending an empty string to your other concatenated values.  Please add sensible spacing to your code in accordance with PSR-12 coding standards.

Comment: @mickmackusa are you serious?

Comment: I don't personally think my first comment would make a very good joke.

Comment: @mickmackusa oh, my fault. I really think it did.
(I did remove the empty string though, thanks for that)