# How can I loop from an entry in the array to the end? twig/php

Tags: php, loops, twig

I've asked to do a loop into an array who looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 215950741
    [1] => 3900
    [2] => 10527160
    [3] => 2873
...
    [44] => N~~~~
    [45] => N~~~~
    [46] => historico_estados
    [47] => 18/10/2018 16:03:09~10~Solicitada~ARANJUEZ~0~2873~   ~
    [48] => 18/10/2018 16:06:42~13~Aceptada~ARANJUEZ~0~2873~   ~
    [49] => 18/10/2018 18:15:49~3~Tránsito~SANTANDER~0~3900~   ~
    [50] => 18/10/2018 22:28:49~3~Tránsito~PLATVITORIA~0~9001~   ~
    [51] => 19/10/2018 04:19:33~3~Tránsito~PLATMADRID~0~9028~   ~
    [52] => 19/10/2018 08:15:53~2~Reparto~ARANJUEZ~0~2873~   ~
    [53] => 19/10/2018 09:37:00~1~Entregado~RECEPTOR~0~2873~   ~
)
```

I need to loop from the entry 46 of the array to the end, I've tried to do something but isn't working at all, and the plus of this I had to do it solely in Twig, so I am kinda lost. I can get the last entry of the array using the `last`function of twig.. but can't find something to get the last entries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start a foreach loop at a specific index in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229905/how-to-start-a-foreach-loop-at-a-specific-index-in-php)

Comment: `{% for i in array[46:] %}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In twig, you could accomplish this with a for loop:

```
{% for i in 44..array|length-1 %}
    {{ array[i] }}
{% endfor %}
```

See an example output [<kbd>here</kbd>](https://twigfiddle.com/g2h20k).

Additionally (Thanks to [splash58's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949571/how-can-i-loop-from-an-entry-in-the-array-to-the-end-twig-php/52949613#comment92807706_52949571)), you can access via the [slice operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html). From the docs:

> ```
> {% for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][start:length] %}
>     {# ... #}
> {% endfor %}
>
> {{ '12345'[1:2] }} {# will display "23" #}
>
> {# you can omit the first argument -- which is the same as 0 #}
> {{ '12345'[:2] }} {# will display "12" #}
>
> {# you can omit the last argument -- which will select everything till the end #}
> {{ '12345'[2:] }} {# will display "345" #}
> ```

So you can accomplish this, like below:

```
{% for item in array[44:] %}
   {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

See an example output of this [<kbd>here</kbd>](https://twigfiddle.com/eygsym).

Comment: I guess OP needs it in twig, not PHP.

Comment: That's the point, I can do it on php but I don't know how to reproduce it in Twig. I've take a look into the docs of twig but.. https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

Comment: @wiitohzjeh I've updated my post (I do apologize, read it as PHP when I skimmed over it).

Comment: Thanks, I've finally got it:

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loop` variable inside `for`

```
{% for el in elems %}
    {% if loop.index0 > 45 %}
        {# do some stuff #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable